# fragment refresh?

Tags: java, android

my app consist of main activity with tow fragments and I,m using FragmentStatePagerAdapter with tabs, what I want is to refresh the first fragment every time I click the first fragment's tab or slide to it, I've tried many solutions but non of them seams to work, Im using onStart and setUserVisibleHint so if they both are true the fragment should be refreshed but I'm getting the same content.

my code is below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0f);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }
        });


        }
    }




    class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private String[] fragments  = {"Fragment1","Fragment2"};


        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){

            return fragments[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

---

---

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    private Boolean isVisible = false;
    private Boolean isStarted = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Fragments code 

        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisible && isStarted) {
            refrehList();
            Log.i("Tag", "reloading fragment");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isStarted = true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isStarted = false;
    }

    public void refrehList() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want your fragment to be refreshed, is there any data that has to be updated?

Comment: in fragment 2 I have a gridview adapter with image and checkbox and depend on the state of the check box a url list will be queried and the result will be on fragment 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. In order to refresh the fragment when it becomes visible to the user, you use:

```
  @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        if (visible) {
            Log.i("Tag", "reloading fragment");
        }
    }
```

In your code, it seems that you never set the isStarted flag to true and so you shoot yourself in the leg ;)

Comment: I've done the same solution but the fragment still load the same content

Comment: Have you coded the stuff you actually want to refresh within the `setUserVisibleHint` method?

Comment: no I assumed that the hole fragment would be recreated with this code so the only thing that has in the setUserVisibleHint is the refrehList method

Comment: So there you go, copy and paste the stuff that needs to be updated into the `setUserVisibleHint` method and it will be executed every time the fragment becomes visible to the user. If you feel that this helped, please accept my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried it but still the same issue, I did try it with and without the refrehList method but it has the same result

Comment: 1) Exactly which bit of code you want to be executed when the fragment is refreshed? 2) Looking at your LogCat, do you see the Log entry "reloading fragment"? You can change it to `Log.e("Tag", "reloading fragment");` to make it red and more visible.

Comment: it seems like the error is that the checkbox list is not getting updated so it reloads the same content every time, thank you Matt for your help

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. If your solution is relevant to the question don´t forget to edit your post and include the answer for others to find :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change content of same fragment knowing its position add 
listener to viewpager

```
Handler handler =new Handler();
viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

      }

  @Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if(position==0)
      //handler to ensure that method is called after frament creation (rare bag with state restoration)
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          if(yourFragment!=null)
            yourFragment.refreshMethod();

        }
      });
  }

      @Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

      }
    });
```

Also call int on your `tabReselected(Tab tab)` method 
While you always want to update only first fragment it is wise to keep external reference to it. Generally i recommend to use map to keep references to all fragments with position as a key.